# Xubuntu software updater inquiry

Tags: xubuntu

I've been asked to assist in the update of this Xubuntu 16.04 machine, but before I jump into this, I wanted to verify:

-The owner described me having some warnings (upgrade pop-ups) a few months ago. She turn those down because she was working in a project, and did not want to mess with her work at the time, deciding to postpone the upgrade for later.

-When asked if she had checked the software updater, she says she did, but she found the message "different from the one she had viewed the last time". When I asked her what was the difference, she told me the message offered her to upgrade to "Xubuntu 18.04", not what it was displaying right now.

So, I tested myself, and this is what it shows:

[image: The updater mentions Ubuntu, not Xubuntu]

Now, does that means I will be only assisting her in update her Ubuntu base, and none of the Xubuntu packages from this non-supported version will update? I don't want to nuke this PC and getting myself into trouble.

Comment: Yes, but since no updates are available, your assistance won't be required. There is nothing to update, nothing to jump into, just let your friend know that support ends in April 2021.

Comment: Will an offline update work then? https://docs.xubuntu.org/current/user/C/offline-packages.html

Comment: If all packages are up to date, what will offline update do? It will query the same repositories, and find nothing to update.

Comment: The thing with this system is Xubuntu supports the LTS only for three years. The Ubuntu base is up to date, but the Xubuntu packages are probably without any support. I will advice her a full back up, then a fresh install. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: @mikewhatever, completely agree that upgrades should be planned - seems like we are using different terms but concur. Xubuntu 16.04 reached EOL on April 21, 2019 - the owner can do whatever they wish, but not upgrading seems the unwise option.

Comment: @user535733 Your comment started with "Click 'Upgrade'", and then some good advice was added as an afterthought.

Comment: @mikewhatever fair enough. Removed.

Comment: I think there could be another solution, via Live Update, using Wubi: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TWzh8Z786xI/AAAAAAAADNw/8lXqgCMgicY/ubuntu11.04-installer.png